# RMBP unable shut down after upgrading to macOS 10.12 Sierra (16A323)

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos

After updating to macOS 10.12, it cannot shut down (tried multiple times). I find the following log file. Do

```
Sep 23 10:01:12 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.WebKit.Databases.1FC429A3-756B-4FE6-8B10-73B662C26026[639]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Sep 23 10:01:12 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.WebKit.Networking.5935D713-FD85-48A7-8A75-7AC51E156FAA[599]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: increaseBackoffTimer Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 458 Level: info :: Probe interval changed from 85 sec to 128 sec.
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 781 Level: debug :: Couldn't get best default route
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 804 Level: debug :: adapter lo0, operStatus=1, wifi=no
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 804 Level: debug :: adapter gif0, operStatus=1, wifi=no
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 804 Level: debug :: adapter stf0, operStatus=1, wifi=no
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 804 Level: debug :: adapter en0, operStatus=1, wifi=no
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 804 Level: debug :: adapter en1, operStatus=1, wifi=no
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 804 Level: debug :: adapter en2, operStatus=1, wifi=no
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 804 Level: debug :: adapter bridge0, operStatus=1, wifi=no
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 804 Level: debug :: adapter p2p0, operStatus=1, wifi=no
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 804 Level: debug :: adapter awdl0, operStatus=1, wifi=no
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 804 Level: debug :: adapter utun0, operStatus=1, wifi=no
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: CFGUTIL Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: ConfigData.cpp Line: 181 Level: warn :: ISEPostureCFG.xml not found, using defaults
Sep 23 10:01:18 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Sep 23 10:01:18 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: collectTargets Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: SwiftHttpRunner.cpp Line: 980 Level: debug :: Active VPN found and Probe targets: 10.192.0.1 enroll.cisco.com  - Default route , #targets=2
Sep 23 10:01:32 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 syslogd[48]: ASL Sender Statistics
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 Google Chrome[562]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 Google Chrome[562]: objc[562]: __weak variable at 0x610001648b90 holds 0x2121212121212121 instead of 0x610000e20a00. This is probably incorrect use of objc_storeWeak() and objc_loadWeak(). Break on objc_weak_error to debug.
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 diagnosticd[269]: System mode client stopped - Console (496) - clearing mode: 0x8, still active: 0x0
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 Finder[414]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 loginwindow[119]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.AirPlayUIAgent[397]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.wifi.WiFiAgent[403]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.noticeboard.agent[400]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.OSDUIHelper[586]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.cloudphotosd[338]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Siri.agent[389]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ViewBridgeAuxiliary[465]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imklaunchagent[347]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.FolderActionsDispatcher[379]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.coreservices.uiagent[565]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000002.AppleSpell[537]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.lateragent[507]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.adobe.acc.AdobeDesktopService.1940.F6187A73-A3B6-4AB8-BE00-DA9FCA082994[480]): Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.sogou.inputmethod.sogou.2028[350]): Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.sogou.SogouServices[433]): Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15 sent by loginwindow[119]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acwebsecagent[276]: UserNotificationProc - gCurrentConsoleUser NULL
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: MacConsoleUserCallback Thread Id: 0xB089C000 File: main.cpp Line: 560 Level: warn :: login user - User zero logged out. Quit application
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acise[453]: Function: hs_log_free Thread Id: 0xB089C000 File: hs_log.c Line: 436 Level: info :: Logging system shutdown
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 aciseposture[530]: Function: ipc_con_cb Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: posture_ipc.cpp Line: 123 Level: debug :: posture IPC disconnected (0, -6)
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 aciseposture[530]: Function: posture_abort Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: posture_ipc.cpp Line: 348 Level: info :: goodbye (pid: 530)
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 aciseposture[530]: Function: cleanup Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: BaseRole.cpp Line: 31 Level: debug :: end aciseposture
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 aciseposture[530]: Function: hs_log_free Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: hs_log.c Line: 436 Level: info :: Logging system shutdown
Sep 23 10:01:44 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acvpnagent[54]: Function: internalReadSocket File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/UdpTcpTransports_unix.cpp Line: 504 Invoked Function: ::read Return Code: -31588336 (0xFE1E0010) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_SHUTDOWN:The socket was shutdown by the operating system or a remote peer. 
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acvpnagent[54]: Function: callbackHandler File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/SocketTransport.cpp Line: 1751 Invoked Function: CSocketTransport::internalReadSocket Return Code: -31588336 (0xFE1E0010) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_SHUTDOWN:The socket was shutdown by the operating system or a remote peer. 
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acvpnagent[54]: Function: OnSocketReadComplete File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/IPCTransport.cpp Line: 910 Invoked Function: CSocketTransport::readSocket Return Code: -31588336 (0xFE1E0010) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_SHUTDOWN:The socket was shutdown by the operating system or a remote peer. 
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 acvpnagent[54]: Function: OnIpcMessageReceived File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/IPCDepot.cpp Line: 1070 Invoked Function: CIpcTransport::OnSocketReadComplete Return Code: -31588336 (0xFE1E0010) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_SHUTDOWN:The socket was shutdown by the operating system or a remote peer. 
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 aciseagentd[103]: Function: ipc_con_cb Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: agent_ipc.cpp Line: 180 Level: warn :: agent IPC disconnected (0, -6)
Sep 23 10:01:44 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 aciseagentd[103]: Function: handle_ipc_con_error Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: agent_ipc.cpp Line: 60 Level: debug :: MSG_PP_IPC_DISCONNECTED, 
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 aciseagentd[103]: Function: handleMessage Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: mod_agent.cpp Line: 79 Level: debug :: agent: received msg [type=185270276][size=0]
Sep 23 10:01:44 wirelessprv-10-194-240-76 aciseagentd[103]: Function: processMessage Thread Id: 0xA50C11C0 File: VlanMonitor.cpp Line: 775 Level: debug :: ISE Posture stopped. VLAN detection is disabled.
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, but my logs are: 24 Eyl 2016 22:59:01 Finder[326]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked 24 Eyl 2016 22:59:01 loginwindow[108]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked 24 Eyl 2016 22:59:01 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[108] 24 Eyl 2016 22:59:01 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: Service exited with abnormal code: 1 24 Eyl 2016 22:59:01 com.apple.x

Comment: Have you tried, automator - new - quit all - run? there could be something in the way of the shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know how exactly this worked out. But it works. Please checkout the following link.

Reinstall MySQL: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7677685

Reset SMC https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Reset NVRAM support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: What's the rationale behind reinstalling MySQL? I read that it's not even included in macOS by default – correct?

Comment: I used it for personal use. It's running in the background all the time as a server.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot log out (Shift - Command - Q) then you may have to force quit apps (also in the Apple Menu).

If the system is wedged, you can either wait or hold the power button to force down the Mac.

At that point, you'll need to try things like safe boot to isolate the core OS from the third party and advanced functions that are enabled during a normal boot.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What should I check after entering the safe mode.